# Blender texture ao bake problem

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

I had two problem for this case ,strange dot and weir line ,and I also new for this.

[image]

[image]

this is setting:

[image]

[image]

and my file :
https://pasteall.org/blend/1fda215e374a40e69ea0c8735af44791

---

For that guys response ,it will turn like this ,that dot has average well but "that line" is still here and is not only in one place.

[image]

this is setting:

[image]

and case:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I don't know what is this, and I'm not mark sharp this line :
[image]

my blender file :
https://pasteall.org/blend/419a664b95a44f40bbbdd179a7514de2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lower the noise threshold in your render settings.

[image]

Also I'm not entirely sure, maybe you have other objects in this model that I can't see but if no, I would recommend you you repack your UVs to utilize more space in the texture. That can increase pixelation in your bake as well, but this may only be part of the model.

**EDIT --** *Additional info:*

More geometry to the problem areas with the fading lines on the inside of the barrel seems  to fix that problem.

Probably has to do with one baker "ray" coming from a single vert at the end has to account for the entire length of the barrel and that leads to distortion.

*Before*

[image]

*After*

[image]

I'm not really able to get rid of the noise inside the barrel, but I don't think it really matters that much, since it will never really be visible to the camera.

The part on the round drum also can be solved by adding more geometry.

[image]

You can kind of understand where those sharp lines come from. Since the n-gon is still in "n-gon land" and hasn't been resolved into quads or triangles, it's state is kind of still up in the air.

In theory, if we triangulated it, it could look like this:

[image]

Or like this:

[image]

Because the baker is probably not triangulating it beforehand, when it's baking each pixel it kind of has to "guess" where the ray should be coming from and might be flipping between these two triangulated states every other pixel.

If you add some more geo and clean it up a bit:

[image]

We can get this result:

[image]

I'm more partial to cleaning it up like that, but even just triangulating the mesh leads to this result.

*Add a Triangulate Modifier*

[image]

Triangulated:

[image]

Triangulated baking result:

[image]

When you triangulate your mesh you can more easily see where other problems with long skinny geo or weird splitting might come from.

[image]

[image]

These spots haven't cause problems in the AO bake, but might be an issue when it comes to normal map baking.

In conclusion:

1. When in doubt, add more geometry.
2. Don't leave massive n-gons unresolved.

Comment: Hi ,sorry I'm late to reply response ,for your response my weird dot had turn as well ,but "that line" ,wherever repack uv(use smart vu project) or do other think "that line" is still here.

Comment: I added more info to my post. Tell me if you need help understanding anything.